# Change base url of a react app in NX workspace

Tags: reactjs, nx.dev

I have a nx workspace where I have several react apps. One of them is `payment` and I want to serve it under `mybaseurl.com/payment` . The static assets (css, js) are failing to load because they are still pointed at root in the index.html. I cannot seem to change the `PUBLIC_URL` to `"/payment"` so that all the static files are served from `mybaseurl.com/payment` instead of `mybaseurl.com`.
I have tried putting `PUBLIC_URL="mybaseurl.com/payment"` in the .env file as well as, `PUBLIC_URL="mybaseurl.com/payment" nx build payment --prod` but nothing seems to have any result.

How can I change PUBLIC_URL here during build time?

For ref, use of PUBLIC_URL: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Example code:

Currently the build is generating the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Payment</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.eb84118aca9dde73dfd8.css">. 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.0e4338761429b4eb16ac.css">


</head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="runtime.28c323bf8ee123f67bad.esm.js" type="module"> </script>
    <script src="polyfills.dd856a07eb47f9259494.esm.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="main.705bf19aea16ed7111ba.esm.js" type="module"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

But I want the build to generate the follwing in the index.html,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Payment</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/payment/styles.eb84118aca9dde73dfd8.css">. 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/payment/main.0e4338761429b4eb16ac.css">


</head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/payment/runtime.28c323bf8ee123f67bad.esm.js" type="module"> </script>
    <script src="/payment/polyfills.dd856a07eb47f9259494.esm.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="/payment/main.705bf19aea16ed7111ba.esm.js" type="module"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you changed the `homepage` entry in the `package.json` file? Set the `basename` prop of the router? Where are these static assets in relation to the `"/payment"` directory on the server? Can you share any of the code you've tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: although changing `homepage` is not an option for me as I have other apps that are not going under `/payment`, I did add an entry in my package.json for `homepage` to `/payment` with no luck.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a `react-router` issue. Is there a build script you are using to generate the `index.html` file? A template file that has the script tags injected?

Comment: No build script, Just the `nx build` , and I have removed react-router tag, as it's not a react-router issue

Comment: Did you figure this out?
If you are leveraging executors then you would add `"baseHref": "/payment/",` to your build options. This worked for me. However, I'm having trouble setting a matching value as the basename for react router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serve the app under base url `mybaseurl.com/payment` , then during build you have to pass a flag,`base-href`, so the command to build your app would be,

```
nx build payment --base-href mybaseurl.com/payment
```

As a result of the flag, the generated index.html output will contain,

```
<base href="mybaseurl.com/payment">
```

and it will make browser lookup all of your scripts and assets on `mybaseurl.com/payment` instead of `mybaseurl.com`

Comment: appears it either `base` or `baseHref` now, at least with the vite builder for react - https://nx.dev/packages/vite/executors/build#base

Answer (score 0):

i set the "baseHref" property in the production config in the project.json and then it appeared in the generated index.html
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those using the "nx-electron" plugin, you can achieve what @Anik suggested by adding the following under `targets.build.options` in your project's `project.json` file (i.e. `apps/<project-name>/project.json`)

```
        "base": "./"
```

This has the same behaviour as adding `--base ./` to your build command.

I would also suggest to add `"emptyOutDir": true`, to make remove the existing previous dist folder. Otherwise, you'll see this:

```
(!) outDir /path/to/project/dist/apps/desktop-app is not inside project root and will not be emptied.
Use --emptyOutDir to override.
```

FYI: I created this project using the `react-monorepo` preset.

```
$ npx create-nx-workspace@17 react-electron-monorepo --preset=react-monorepo

✔ Application name · react-app
✔ Which bundler would you like to use? · vite
✔ Test runner to use for end to end (E2E) tests · playwright
✔ Default stylesheet format · css
✔ Do you want Nx Cloud to make your CI fast? · skip
```

Then install the nx-electron plugin:

```
$ npm install -D nx-electron
$ nx g nx-electron:app electron-app --frontendProject=react-app
$ npx nx add @nx/jest
$ npm i -D webpack-node-externals
```

Finally, add the following to the root of your main `package.json`:

```
  "build": {
    "executableName": "react-app",
    "artifactName": "react-app-${version}.${ext}"
  },
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to achieve this is to change the `base` tag by editing `apps/payment/src/index.html`:

```
<base href="/payment/">
```

The browser will then prepend the path to those assets.

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt work

Comment: @Anik this is working for my Nx workspace React apps served under subdirectories (with the addition of some config for CloudFront & S3 as they're deployed to AWS). If you could create a reproducible example of your setup I might be able to help.